# HighChart - PieChart - Append image in center

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highchart - Pichart to display some information.

I am also appending image to that piechart using below code.

---

### chart.renderer.image('../assets/images/icon_chart_123.png', 244, 167, 60, 60).add();

Here, 244 and 167 are X and Y

When I try to check screen with large resolution the image is not getting in center.

So, the main course is I want to append a single image in center of Hightchart - PieChart.

Comment: Please share the rest of the code you have

Comment: You need to calculate `x` and `y` values according to the size of the container. Note: use absolute paths, otherwise chart will not display the icon when exporting to image/pdf.